# Как посчитать количество заглавных и строчных букв в строке?

Tags: python, строки

Как посчитать количество заглавных и строчных букв в строке?

Comment: `sum(i.isupper() for i in s), sum(i.islower() for i in s)`

Comment: "Заглавные" и "прописные" - это одно и то же.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18129830/9210255

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, как-то так:

```
s = "ПриВет кУлхацКЕр!"
print(f'Заглавных букв: {sum(map(str.isupper, s))}, строчных: {sum(map(str.islower, s))}')
```

Вывод:

```
Заглавных букв: 5, строчных: 10
```

Comment: а можно решить через for и if с счетчиком?

Comment: @popovpetrrr Можно. Решайте :)  Если это задание, то не поленитесь, сделайте сами, задания дают, чтобы вы учились.

Comment: @popovpetrrr, лучше учиться на идиоматичных примерах! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Заглавные

```
print(sum(map(str.isupper, input())))
```

для строчных `islower()`

Comment: И чем это по сути отличается от предыдущего ответа двухлетней давности, кроме ухудшения качества?